# Using automatic as parameters

Tags: c, automatic-storage

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(auto int i); // line 3

int main()
{
    foo(10);
}

void foo(auto int i) // line 13
{
    printf("%d\n", i );
}
```

What is wrong in this code?
This program is not compiling.

Errors I am seeing are as follows:

```
main.c:3:27: error: storage class specified for parameter 'i'
     void foo(auto int i);

main.c:13:27: error: storage class specified for parameter 'i'
     void foo(auto int i)
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `auto` is an obsolete qualifier for local variables, not function parameters.

Comment: @PaulR why obsolete ? I don't think so.

Comment: If the code is not compiling, you ***must*** describe the compilation error you saw, including what line number it references.  ***VTC***

Comment: @Zaffy: If not obsolete, then at least redundant, which amounts to the same thing in practice.

Comment: Not sure why this question received three down votes, especially after the OP added the error messages when asked for.

Comment: My guess would be that the down-votes are most likely for (i) no attempt to research `auto` keyword, (ii) no attempt to interpret fairly self-evident error message. A quick Google search would have turned up all the relevant information without the need to post a question.

Comment: Better just not to use `auto` unless you're writing C++ i.e. C++11. C++11 most likely chose that keyword because no one is using it anymore for its original meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only *storage class specifier* that is valid in a parameter declaration is *register*, we can see this from the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section  `6.7.5.3` *Function declarators (including prototypes)* paragraph *2* which says:

> The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is register.

this is section `6.7.6.3` in *C11*.

the *storage class specifiers* from section `6.7.1` *Storage-class specifiers* are as follows:

```
typedef
extern
static
auto
register
```

Comment: the section is 6.7.6.3

Comment: @PankajMahato in C11 that is the correct section, I usually quote C99 unless the OP specifically asks about C11.

Comment: Can you please give me the link of C11 standard?

Comment: @PankajMahato you can find almost all of the draft standards C and C++ [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).

Answer (score 3):

`auto` is a storage class specifier. This is used for local variables(*automatic local variables*) You can't put it in the declaration of function parameter.

On compiling you should get the error:

```
[Error] storage class specified for parameter 'i'
```

In C, You are not allowed to put a storage class specifier in the parameter declaration (except `register`)

Comment: what is the meaning of this?